# How do I send the score over to another scene?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I need some help sending the player's score when they lost over to another scene but can't figure out how.

This is the code I have right now:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(playerOne.boundingbox, object.boundingbox))
{

    [self gameOver];
};

-(void)gameOver
{
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameOver scene] withTransition:[CCTransistion transitionFadeWithDuration:1]
}
```

So basicly when these two's bounding box collide, the game is over and send you over to the gameOver scene.

How can I send over the score over to the Game Over scene too?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property into the `GameOver` class named `score`.  Then, before you replace the scene, set the `score` property to whatever the score is.

Example (note: this is untested so some types might be wrong as I've never used Cocos2d):

```
-(void)gameOver {

    NSInteger score = /* get the score here */;

    GameOver *scene = [GameOver scene];
    [scene setScore:score];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene withTransition:[CCTransistion transitionFadeWithDuration:1]];

}
```

Now, you can just fetch the score in the `GameOver` scene like so:

```
-(void)someMethod {

    NSInteger score = [self score];
    NSLog("Score: %d",score);

}
```

Comment: I will try later. When setting the property for score, do i put it as @property(weak, assign) or @property(strong, assign)?

Comment: Depends on the type of the property.  If it's a primitive value, you want to have it as assign (weak isn't necessary) but if it's an object you'll generally want it to be strong.

Comment: Where do you get setScore from in gameOver method?

Comment: In the GameOver class, create a property named "score".  Ex: @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger score;

Comment: [scene setScore:score];   -- the setScore. I've already made a property "score"

Comment: setScore is the automatic setter made by the property declaration.

Comment: The code works but somehow it return a score of "0".